# How Do I Nest IF Functions in Order to Calculate Daily Revenue?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, nested-if

I am working on a data set and I need to calculate the daily revenue of fake AirBnb listings using nested IF statements. This is for a bootcamp I am attending, and I am stuck.

My instructions are as follows:

**Estimate revenue per listing**

- Assume each booking always has 2 guests, unless the listing accommodates only one;
- The booking is always for the minimum number of days allowed;
- Only half of the bookings generate a review;
- The extra person charge is per night (column name ‘extra_people’)

○   Format: have a column that calculates daily revenue (account for number of guests accommodated, number of guests included in the price, extra charge for additional people - using nested IF statements); another column would then calculates revenue per booking; finally, multiply that by the number of total stays the listings has had.

Using the data in my dataset, I am attempting to fill out column AA. So far this is what I have for my formula,

[image: Formula]

However, I get an error. I know the first part of this formula would work for the scenario in row 4. However, I need to make sure that the formula takes into account scenarios where the "guests included" is less than the "accommodates", because I must assume that each booking always has two guests except for when the listing only accommodates one person.

How should this formula be written? Can I not create equations within nested if formulas if it includes adding, subtracting, dividing, or multiplying columns together?

[image: Dataset]

Comment: With nested `IF` statements you write the first `IF` formula then lead into the next `IF` statement from the `FALSE` value for the previous `IF`. For example your formula written correctly would be: `=IF(W4=Q4,V4,IF(W4<Q4,Q4*V4))+X4`

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the previous response a bit more, the structuring of `IF`statements is important. Keep in mind the structure of the function: `=IF(logical test, value if true, value if false)`. So, the second `IF` function (the first nested) needs to be placed where the first "value if false" comes in - each additional `IF` needs to be within the previous `IF` function. Using your example, the corrected form would be `=IF(W4=Q4,V4,IF(W4<Q4,Q4*V4...))`. I'm not sure what the "+X4" is supposed to be adding to, but this hopefully makes the structure clearer for you to work with. Good luck!